# How can this be broken up into a math statement?

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm trying to solve this question: "Prove or disprove that the product of two irrational numbers is irrational" but I am having trouble breaking this question up into a math statement.

Is an appropriate statement "If a and b are irrational, then ab is irrational"?

Comment: Sure.  Again, though, they are asking you to prove that (if it is true) or to disprove it (if it is false).  Hint:  if it is false, a single counterexample is all you need to disprove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a correct formulation of the statement you need to prove or disprove.

What do you think? Is the statement true or false?

Comment: I think it is false.  One counterexample is a = b = $\sqrt{2}$.  Then $ab = 2$ which is rational.

Comment: And that's a valid disproof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is an appropriate statement. In fact, that is a good proposition with which to begin a proof by way of *reductio ad absurdum*.